# Python subprocess.Popen() - subprocess causes sockets to remain open

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, subprocess

I have a Python2.7 script that does some parallelism magic and finally enters Flask gui_loop.  At some point a thread creates a background process with subprocess.Popen. This works.

When my script exits and if the subprocess is still running, I can't run my script again, as flask gui_loop fails with:

```
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

With netstat -peanut I can see the ownership of the socket transfers to the child process when the python script exits. This is how it looks when both python script and subprocess are running:

```
root@test:/tmp# netstat -peanut | grep 5000
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       840210      21458/python
```

After terminating the Python script, socket does not close but its ownership is passed to the child process:

```
root@test:~/PycharmProjects/foo/gui# netstat -peanut | grep 5000
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       763103      19559/my-subprocess
```

Is there any way around this? The subprocess (written in C) is not doing anything on that socket and doesn't need it. Can I somehow create a subprocess without passing the gui loop socket resource to it?

I can of course terminate the process but this is not ideal as the purpose of this is to build a simple gui around some calculations and not lose the progress if the gui script happens to exit. I would have a mechanism to reattach connection to the subprocess if I just could get the gui script up and running again.

R

Comment: I got the exact same thing with Python 2.7 for kicking start a daemon program within Django server, and it works fine with Python 3.7. When the Django server exited, the daemon program keeps holding the Django server port. The accepted answer solves this kind of problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [`close_fds=True`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) when creating the subproces, which will cause all file descriptors (and therfore open sockets) to be closed in the child process (except for stdin/stdout/stderr).

In newer versions (python 3.2+) `close_fds` already defaults to `True`, as in most cases you don't want to inherit all open file descriptors in a child process, but in python2.7 you still need to specify it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the ***with*** statement. Some documentation here:

```
http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example/
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/
```

This does open/close cleanup for you.